# How to run a background work in Oreo when a user unlocks the screen?

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo, android-jobscheduler, android-background

Is there any way to run background work when user unlocks the screen in Android O (app is in background state)? As far as I know broadcast actions like `android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT` won't work anymore and JobScheduler has no conditions for such event. Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way to run background work when user unlocks the screen
>   in Android O (app is in background state)?

Unfortunately a normal app cannot monitor device unlock action. If your app is enabled as [DeviceAdmin](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin#developing), then there is a chance to detect when user has unlocked the phone. But this will only be received the first time user succeed after having previously failed to unlock the device.